# Where to find Oracle Certificate Topics

Tags: java, certificate

i want to train for the Oracle Certificate Associate Java 8 and I cannot find on their website what topics should I learn.
Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are talking about first level(**OCA**) of certification exam.

[image]

**Java SE 8 Programmer I**

**Exam Number**: 1Z0-808

**Exam Title**: Java SE 8 Programmer I

**TOPICS** :

- Java Basics
- Working With Java Data Types
- Using Operators and Decision Constructs
- Creating and Using Arrays
- Using Loop Constructs
- Working with Methods and Encapsulation
- Working with Inheritance
- Handling Exceptions
- Working with Selected classes from the Java API

[link](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-808) for Oracle website -> Review Exam Topics